# interbase error in select statement

Tags: php, syntax-error, interbase

Dear all I got error from my php:

```
PHP Warning:  ibase_query(): Dynamic SQL Error expression evaluation not supported Strings cannot be added or subtracted in dialect 3  in /home/jeinqa/www/oqc/getsch.php on line 22
```

come from my script :

```
define("DBNAME","10.230.38.111:/var/lib/firebird/data/OCS_FA.fdb");
define("DBUSER","USER"); // user name
define("DBPASS","USER"); // password
$dbh = ibase_connect(DBNAME,DBUSER,DBPASS) or die(_ERROR15.": ".ibase_errmsg());

    $stmt = "SELECT FIRST 10 LINE_NAME, MODEL_ONLY || ' ' || VER_ONLY as MODEL, PROD_NO,
                     (RIGHT(SERIAL_NO_UP,-4)-RIGHT(SERIAL_NO_LOW,-4))+1 as QTY, START_SERIAL, 
                        SERIAL_NO_LOW, SERIAL_NO_UP, PROD_DATE 
                FROM DOC_TO";
    $sth = ibase_query($dbh, $stmt);
```

This is first time I'm using interbase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to subtract 2 strings (`RIGHT(SERIAL_NO_UP,-4)` and `RIGHT(SERIAL_NO_LOW,-4)`.

Instead, `CAST` these values to integers before trying to do math on them:

```
(CAST(RIGHT(SERIAL_NO_UP,-4) AS INTEGER)-CAST(RIGHT(SERIAL_NO_LOW,-4)
AS INTEGER))+1 as QTY
```